# Android Studio searching for libraries with incorrect ABI

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to connect Android Studio v2.2.1 with ndk-build v13 to build my Cocos2d-x project on Android.

I've specified `APP_ABI := armeabi` inside of my `Application.mk` file, but when I try to sync the project with the Gradle files I get the following error:

`Android NDK: Check that .../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/arm64-v8a/libfreetype.a exists  or that its path is correct`

Notice that it's looking for non-existent **`arm64-v8a`** prebuilt libraries even though I've specified my ABI as armeabi in my `Application.mk`.

What could be causing it to ignore the value I've specified and choose an incorrect ABI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app/build.gradle's default has higher priority over Application.mk; use

```js
android {
    defaultConfig {
      ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' // more could be added
      }
  }
}
```

as in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/teapots/classic-teapot/build.gradle.

Comment: This was it! I did some searching trying to figure this out on my own but all I could really find connecting Gradle and setting the ABI seemed to be related to creating split APKs, which wasn't really what I wanted to do. Thanks so much for your assistance!